# MVC.NET Tracing Partials & Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, trace, razor-2

Is there a way to get a trace of what cshtml files are being used to construct a particular page load?  For instance:

- /Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml

  - /Views/Shared/_UserNavigation.cshtml
  - /Views/Shared/_BannerSelector.cshtml
  - RenderBody - /Views/Users/Index.cshtml

    - /Views/Users/DisplayTemplate/User.cshtml
    - Anything else used to construct view
  - /Views/Shared/_UserFooter.cshtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). It works much like Firebug does, except for MVC. It shows the execution tree of your views/partials/layout in a tree that looks pretty much the same as you described, including their execution times. It's very extensible as well, and there are plugins to trace Entity Framework, and JavaScript, etc.